# How to separate substrings in a cell into array in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if anyone can give me some pointers. I have one column with data arrange like this in each cell:

```
Column E

E1-  name-age(nickname)   name-age(nickname)   name-age(nickname) ....
E2-  name-age(nickname)   name-age(nickname)   name-age(nickname) ....
etc...
```

the problem is its all in one column, and I know I can use text to column feature and delimit them by space. However, is there a more elegant way to do this? I'd like to do it over vba if possible.

My end goal is to capture each "name-age(nickname)" couplets into an array. Currently what I have started on vba -wise is

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    Details = Cells(i, 5).Value  // where the big column data is located
    tempString = Left(Details, InStr(Details, "  "))
End Sub
```

With this, I could only get the first name-age(nickname) couplet in that cell.. is there a better way to approch this?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: See [this useful discussion](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s224/split-join-array.htm) of getting strings into arrays, especially with the Split function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are naming your subroutine as `Split` columns but there's no split function used.

You have two options:

1. Split by space

E.g. cellvalue is just the variable name that refers to your cell. For multiple cells you may loop through.

```
  vArray As Variant
  vArray = Split(cellvalue, " ")
```

1. Make use of `Text to Columns` wizard in menu bar. Then transpose or dump the range into a variant array.

E.g.

```
vArray = Sheets(1).Range("A1:H10").value
```